# SQL Join Table and Find Max

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, max, threshold

I have two tables XY and Tops. I am trying to use MS ACCESS and SQL to join these tables (on wid) but only keep the max Tops.Depth_Top less than XY.TVD for each XY.wid.
I am fairly new to SQL but have made the following two queries. The first one identifies all data that are above a threshold (Depth_Tops <= TVD).

```
    SELECT DISTINCT XY.wid, Tops.Name, Tops.Depth_Top, XY.TVD 
    INTO Result_SQ
    FROM Tops 
    INNER JOIN XY 
    ON Tops.wid = XY.wid
    WHERE (((Tops.Depth_Top)<=[XY].[TVD]))
    ORDER BY XY.wid, Tops.Depth_Top
```

The second query takes the results from the first and only keeps the max Depth_Top.

```
    SELECT * INTO Unique_Result_SQ
    FROM Result_SQ AS t1
    WHERE (((t1.Depth_Top)=(Select MAX(Depth_Top)
    From Result_SQ t2
    Where t2.XY_wid = t1.XY_wid
    Group BY t2.XY_wid)));
```

These queries achieve the desired results if both are executed independently, however, I am having trouble combining the two into one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need all those SELECT INTO s (you can add them if you really need it) but i would just add the Max to the select list instead of WHERE:

```
SELECT 
    XY.wid, Tops.Name, XY.TVD , 
    Max(Tops.Depth_Top)
FROM Tops JOIN XY 
    ON Tops.wid = XY.wid
WHERE Tops.Depth_Top =< XY.TVD
Group BY XY.wid, Tops.Name, XY.TVD
```

based on your comments, I understand that you want the max of each group in your resultset. In order to do that, you have to first assign a ROW_NUMBER to each row in each group, and then in the final SELECT, choose only the RN=1 (top result), so your code would look like this:

```
WITH CTE_RN AS
(
SELECT 
    XY.wid, Tops.Name, XY.TVD , 
    Max(Tops.Depth_Top),
    ROW_NUMBER ( )   
      OVER (PARTITION BY XY.wid 
        ORDER BY Tops.Depth_Top DESC ) AS RN  
FROM Tops JOIN XY 
    ON Tops.wid = XY.wid
WHERE Tops.Depth_Top =< XY.TVD
Group BY XY.wid, Tops.Name, XY.TVD 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_RN WHERE RN=1
```

I haven't tested it but it should give you the idea

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code returns the same results as my first query.

Not sure if this is the reason, but the wid and Name are independent of each other.

http://imgur.com/a/EFlvN

I would like to remove the highlighted rows along with the bottom two rows.

Comment: so you only want one row to be returned?

Comment: In this example it would be two rows (wid 0 and 1). The original tables have depths that are both less than and greater than TVD. I would like to only keep information associated with the biggest depth less than TVD for each wid.